# Ignore folders during webOS TV build

Tags: eclipse, smarty, webos, lg

I am using webOS IDE for SmartTV Developers Build 1062 to. Is there a way I can ignore some folders from being built and packaged into *.ipk file?

Answer (score 1):

Yes, sure you can do that. When you click on project and export IPK then select non-minify. Then in the box down below you can select the files and folders you want in the IPK and un-select the files and folders you don't want in the IPK.[image: The image is attached for the reference.]

Comment: Can this be done while running the application directly from the IDE? I do not see this option while running or debugging.